# How does Entity Framework Core handle instances before context is saved?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

How does Entity Framework work when something like the following occurs:

```
var myInstance = new MyObject();

// Do stuff

_myContext.MyObjects.Add(myInstance);

myInstance = null;

_myContext.SaveChanges();
```

I ran into this happening in a complex foreach-call and it still seem to do what was expected. But I am curious how it handles it and if it gives up tracking the object when the instance is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am curious how it handles it and if it gives up tracking the object when the instance is null

In your example, the instance is *not* `null` - just the *variable* `myInstance` value is `null`, i.e. the variable does not hold reference to the object you've created.

What about how EF Core tracks the instances, in simplified form you can think of that as `MyObjects` being a `List<MyObject>` (the actual implementation of course is different). So what happens when you do something like this:

```
var myObjects = new List<MyObject>();

var myInstance = new MyObject();

// Do stuff

myObjects.Add(myInstance);

myInstance = null;
```

`myInstance` variable is `null`, but `myObjectList` holds a reference to the created object (i.e. is "tracking" it), so it can always be get back, in this case with

```
var trackedInstance = myObjects[0];
```

Again, the actual implementation is different, but the concept is the same - the `DbContext` instance contains some sort of a list with all "tracked" entity instances and their state (`Added`, `Deleted`, etc.).

Comment: Okay! I understand. The thing that made me curious was that the list running through the loop gave me the error: "The instance of entity type 'MyObject' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value..." until it was marked as null for each instance. Then it did what was expected.